# Airflow DataprocClusterCreateOperator

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

In Airflow DataprocClusterCreateOperator settings:

Do we have a chance to set the Primary disk type for master and worker to `pd-ssd`?

The default setting is `standard`.

I was looking into the documentation - I don't find any parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no option to change the Disk Type in `DataprocClusterCreateOperator`.

In Google API it is available if you pass a parameter to https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters#diskconfig

I will try and add this feature and should be available in **Airflow 1.10.1** or **Airflow 2.0**.

For now, you can create an Airflow plugin that modifies the current `DataprocClusterCreateOperator`.

Comment: Modified DataprocClusterCreateOperator and its working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two fields in regard to this:

```
master_machine_type: Compute engine machine type to use for the master node
worker_machine_type: Compute engine machine type to use for the worker nodes
```

I have found this simply looking into the source code here (this is for latest, but no version was provided so I assumed the latest version):

https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.html

Comment: Customized DataprocClusterCreateOperator, Added "bootDiskType" for master and worker its working fine Thanks